# Where do I put an ETag, and what is the format?

Tags: html

I currently put this `<meta cache-control: public ETag: "v019" />`
in the `<head>` just under the `<title>`, but keep getting Errors in the W3 validator.

What is the format and where do I put this in my HTML5 file?

Comment: This “ <meta cache-control: public ETag: "v019" />” seems to be stripped from my question!

Comment: — The question editor does include formatting instructions and a toolbar with helpful buttons.

Comment: Note that the `<meta>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

An ETag isn't useful unless it is in a real HTTP header. It shouldn't be in your HTML document at all.

That said, the syntax for an HTML meta tag with a simulation of an HTTP header is:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" value="public">
<meta http-equiv="ETag" value="&quot;v019&quot;">
```

`cache-control` and `ETag` are not [accepted values](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-meta-http-equiv) for it in HTML 5. You would need to be using HTML 4 or earlier (although it would still be pointless).